# Another oddness with ObjC inheritance

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have another odd problem with Objective C inheritance. I have a protocol called IGameObject, a class GameObject that inherits from NSObject and IGameObject and finally a Player that inherits from GameObject..

The problem is that when I assign a Player* to a IGameObject*, this produces an error, but it works ok when I assign a Player* to a GameObject*. I haven't seen that this is not possible in all I have read. Here the code:

```
-(IGameObject*) clone
{
    Player* p=(Player*) 0xFFfFFFFF;
    //Throws an error saying that Cannont initialise a variable of type IGameObject with an value of           Player*
    IGameObject* go=p;

    //This works perfectly
    GameObject* go2=p;

    return [[Player alloc] initWithGameObject:self];
 }
```

Could anybody guess what is happening?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When returning (or declaring) a type that is only known by its interface, don't treat it as an object pointer. Instead, use:

```
-(id<IGameObject>) clone {
```

And:

```
id<IGameObject> go=p;
```

This should clear up that warning.

**Sidenote:** Why in the *world* are you assigning `p` to a memory address?!

Comment: It was just a fast test to see where the problem was. That was it, thanks a lot for the fast answer.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a pointer to a protocol

```
IGameObject* go=p;
```

is meaningless.